# PHP assigning numeric values to strings in an array

Tags: php, arrays, key

Hi everyone I am new to PHP, and would appreciate some of your help

I am currently building a black Jack Game, and need some help with how the Values of an array are displayed in a browser, I currently have the array for the Cards set like this:

```
  private $suits = array('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades');
private $cards = array(
'Ace'=> 1, 
2 => 2, 
3 => 3, 
4 => 4, 
5 => 5, 
6 => 6, 
7 => 7, 
8 => 8, 
9 => 9, 
10 => 10, 
'Jack' => 10, 
'Queen'=>10, 
'King'=>10);
```

It does what it is suppose to do and does the math how it should. It gives the Jack, Queen, and king the values it should so if a King is paired with a seven it will add 17. My problem with this is that in the browser the Jack, Queen, and King, are displayed as "10" instead of being displayed with the string, so it looks like they are not being accounted for. I would like to know if there is a way to have the string displayed instead without loosing the numeric value. I tried inverting like so

```
10 => 'King',
```

And by doing this King gets displayed but the numeric value is not accounted, so a person with a 7 will beat a person with a King.

Any help will be greatly appreciated... Thanks

EDIT ***

I am adding in the full code, there are four different php files.

Card.php

```
    class Card
    {
    private $suit;
    private $figure;


    public function __construct($Suit, $Fig) {
            $this->suit   = $Suit;
            $this->figure = $Fig;
    }

    public function __toString() {
            return $this->figure . ' of ' . $this->suit;
    }

    public function getFigure() {
            return $this->figure;
    }

    public function getCard() {
            echo $this->figure . " of " . $this->suit . ".<br />";
    }
    }
```

Deck.php

```
     abstract class Deck
    {
protected $arrCards; 
protected $listOfCards;

/* abstract methods force classes that extends this class to implement them */
abstract public function dealCard(); //all classes that will inherit will inherit this method


/* already implemented methods */
public function __construct($Cards) {
    $this->arrCards = $Cards;
}

public function shuffleCards() {
    shuffle($this->arrCards);
}

public function listCards() {
    foreach($this->arrCards as $Card) {
        echo $Card . '<br />';
    }
}

    }
```

EnglishDeck.php

```
    include_once "Deck.php"; 
    include_once "Card.php"; 

    class EnglishDeck extends Deck
    {   

private $suits = array('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades');
private $cards = array( 
    1=> 'Ace', 
    2=> '2' , 
    3 => '3',
    4 => '4', 
    5=> '5' , 
    6 => '6',
    7 => '7',
    8=> '8' , 
    9 => '9',
    10 => '10',
    10 =>'Jack', 
    10=>'Queen', 
    10=>'King'
    );


public function dealCard() {
    return array_pop($this->arrCards);
}

public function __construct() {
    $Cards = $this->initEnglishDeck();
    parent::__construct($Cards);
}

function initEnglishDeck() {
    $arrCards = array();

    foreach($this->suits as $Suit) {
        foreach ($this->cards as $Card) {
            $arrCards[] = new Card($Suit, $Card);
        }

    }
    return $arrCards;
}

    }
```

cardgame.php

```
    include_once "Card.php";
    include_once "EnglishDeck.php";


   $oBaraja = new EnglishDeck(); 
   $oBaraja->shuffleCards();


   //PLAYER 1
  $oP1card1  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
  echo("Player one has " . $oP1card1);

  $oP1card2  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
  echo(" and a " . $oP1card2 );

  echo "<br>";

  //PLAYER 2
 $oP2card1  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
 echo("Player two has " . $oP2card1);

 $oP2card2  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
 echo(" and a " . $oP2card2);

 //Player Variables when cards are added together
$oPlayer1 = (string)$oP1card1 + (string)$oP1card2;
$oPlayer2 = (string)$oP2card1 + (string)$oP2card2;


echo "<br />";

if($oPlayer1 > $oPlayer2){
     echo "Player 1 wins";
} else if ($oPlayer1 < $oPlayer2) {
    echo "Player 2 wins";
} else {
   echo "it's a tie";
}
```

This will display in a browser like so:

Player one has 10 of Hearts and a 2 of Clubs
Player two has 10 of Hearts and a 3 of Hearts
Player 2 wins

The problem is one of the 10's should have been a king/queen/jack

Comment: How are you displaying them?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question to show my full code, this is shown in card.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options for doing that. I suggest to build a 2D array like:

```
$this->cards = array(
    'k' => array('name' => 'King', 'value' => 10),
    'q' => array('name' => 'Queen', 'value' => 10),
    'a' => array('name' => 'Ace', 'value' => 1),
    5 => array('name' => '5', 'value' => 5) 
    /* and so on */
);
```

Then you can get name and value easily with:

```
$this->cards['k']['name']; // Label of the card "King" (King)
$this->cards['a']['value']; // Value of the card "Ace" (1)
```

You store the keys of the cards and if you like to display the name you use `$this->cards['{the_key}']['name']` and if you want to display the value or calculate with it use `$this->cards['{the_key}']['value']`.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure where to plug in the $this->cards['k']['name']; // Label of the card "King" (King)
$this->cards['a']['value']; // Value of the card "Ace" (1) to make my code work, any hints?

Comment: It's how you access the two things (label and value) of the card. So where you need the value you can use `$this->cards['{the_key}']['value']` and if you need to print the card name out use `$this->cards['{the_key}']['name']`.